# How to disable linewrap in JLabel even for <html> text

Tags: swing, jtable, jlabel, tablecellrenderer

Whenever JLabel contains text in  tag it applies line wrap automatically (it seems). My requirement is line wrap should always be disabled for label, no matter what text it contains. I can not use JTextArea in my renderer due to legacy reasons.

Comment: AFAIK, a `JLabel` is always single-lined unless it uses html-rendering

Comment: Agreed, but even for html rendering I dont want to line wrap, may be some html tag might help here ?

Answer (score 18):

1. You can use `<nobr></nobr>` tag around the HTML content you don't want to be wrapped
2. Simple non-HTML content will never be wrapped inside the JLabel

Here is an example:

```
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
    frame.setLayout ( new BorderLayout () );

    final String html = "<html><body><nobr>CMV Antigenemia Stat X 2.0 dose(s)</nobr></body></html>";
    final String simple = "<html><body>CMV Antigenemia Stat X 2.0 dose(s)</body></html>";

    JTable table1 = new JTable ( new String[][]{ { html, html, html, html, html } }, new String[]{ html, html, html, html, html } );
    table1.setRowHeight ( 50 );
    frame.add ( table1, BorderLayout.NORTH );

    JTable table2 = new JTable ( new String[][]{ { simple, simple, simple, simple, simple } },
            new String[]{ simple, simple, simple, simple, simple } );
    table2.setRowHeight ( 50 );
    frame.add ( table2, BorderLayout.CENTER );

    frame.pack ();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
    frame.setVisible ( true );
}
```

As you can see - in the 1st table HTML content is not getting wrapped.

Comment: Tried this , but did not worked. I am adding this label to JTable - basically my renderer component is JLabel.

Comment: What exactly did not work? How did you insert `<nobr>` tag around your HTML code? Please add some code into your question that shortly describes the problem.

Comment: I get following text in getTableCellRendererComponent method of my renderer - "<html><body><nobr>CMV Antigenemia Stat X 2.0 dose(s)</nobr></body></html>". Component returned here has to be JLabel due to legacy reasons (Problem could have been solved by textarea.

Comment: @niteen22 you are doing something wrong - check the code i have added in my answer. HTML content you have posted in the last comment doesn't get wrapped (and it shouldn't) - just try resizing the frame. So what is the problem?